# Aligning Div Boxes CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to align the `div`s in a way that on the left there is a big expandable box like the ones you can see and the 2 aligning ones one on top of the other on the right right by it

Imagine, instead of boxes 1&3 that you see in the code I've written, to have them as 1 big box and the other 2&4 stay as they are aligned to the big box.

I've been playing around with the flex command but cant get it to work
every time I use the flex commands it doesn't align properly and becomes a pyramid

If someone can help me out and explain it to me I'd appreciate it as I don't understand how to get it to work

```css
.Scrollbox h1 {
   color: #ffffff !important;     
}
        
.scroll-con {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: center;
} 

.Scrollbox {
   background: rgba(130, 164, 179,0.6);
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   width: 300px;
   height: 250px;
   transition: height 1s ease;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; 
}

.Scrollbox:hover {
   height: 500px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-con">
  <div class="Scrollbox">1</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">2</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">3</div>
  <div class="Scrollbox">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say. What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want 1&3 to be one long box and 2&4 to be 2 individual boxes beside it?

You can split them up into two different divs where 2&4 will be children of the `right` div.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 500px
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.right>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.right>div:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.right>div:last-child {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">1 &amp; 3</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `grid` to do the same.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left {
  min-height: 500px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: pink;
}

.left+div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.left+div+div {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">1 &amp; 3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does .container>div mean? Like what does it do am not familiar with it sorry

Comment: The `>` is a direct child selector which tells CSS to apply the styling to any `div` that is a direct child of `.container`. You can learn more about selectors here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)